# Plane always black

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add a texture to my plane that repeats horizontal and vertical. The thing is, when I try to apply the texture, it is always black. I don't get any errors, and i already tried to add some lights, but the problem is still there; I don't know how to solve it... Here is what I did:

```
window.onload = function init()
{
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = -30;
  camera.position.y = 40;
  camera.position.z = 30;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
  scene.add( light );

  var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff);
  spotlight.position.set( -50, 40, 0 );
  scene.add( spotlight );


var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 ); scene.add(axes);

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  desenhaMapa();

  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

    function desenhaMapa()
{
  labirinto = new THREE.Object3D();

  var texturaPlano = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("texturaPac.jpg");

  geometryPlano = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,50);
  materialPlano = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {map: texturaPlano} );
  var planoPacMan = new THREE.Mesh(geometryPlano,materialPlano);
  planoPacMan.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
  scene.add(planoPacMan);
}
```

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 3):

`TextureLoader.load()` is an asynchronous method. That is why it has an `onload` argument.

You are calling `render()` before the texture loads. One solution is to call `render()` in the loader callback.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture = loader.load( 'myTexture.jpg', function ( texture ) {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

} );
```

Another solution is to have an animation loop. But that is not required for static scenes.

three.js r.78