# Earth picture not rendering with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning Three.js for the first time, and like many others, am trying to create a rotating Earth with the library using [this link](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/). I have set up a local webserver using Express and Node, and I don't get any CORS errors or anything when trying to access the image files. But still all I get is a black canvas. My code:

```
const WIDTH = 800;
const HEIGHT = 400;
const VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
const ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
const NEAR = 0.1;
const FAR = 1000;

const container = document.querySelector('#content');

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR );
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333));
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(5, 3, 5);
scene.add(light);

const earth = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32),
                new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/img/cloudless_world.jpg'),
                    bumpMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/img/bump_world_map.jpg'),
                    bumpScale: 0.005,
                    specularMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/img/specular_world_map.png'),
                    specular: new THREE.Color('grey')
                })
              );
scene.add(earth);
camera.position.set(2, 2, 2);
camera.lookAt(earth.position);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I have seen quite a few posts about problems when trying this, but couldn't find anything to help me fix my code. Can someone help please? Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017970/plane-always-black/38018994#38018994

Comment: You don't have a render loop, same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262199/three-js-not-rendering-cube-with-custom-texture/46264455#46264455