# loaded image textures do not display via three.js unless animated

Tags: three.js, textures

Just beginning with the three.js library and so obviously there is something I am missing or that I don't understand.

I was attempting to create my first 3D object in a scene but have become baffled by a behavior I am noticing. The mesh object that I created is a simple cube shape that is using a loaded image for it's texture.

The textured mesh object looks great in the scene but only if I am repeatedly rendering the scene via the requestAnimationFrame() function. If I try to render the object with only one call to the render() method then the cube appears as solid black color and with no visible texture image on it. I have also noticed that if I use just a plain color for the material instead of an image, then it renders perfectly. For some reason, whenever I attempt to use an image as the material then the cube will only display properly if I constantly re-render the scene inside of a loop.

I am assuming that I should be able to call renderer.render() just once instead of calling it repeatedly inside of a loop. Should not the cube be displayed properly along with it's image texture with only a single call to renderer.render()?? Like I said, if I used a simple color for the cube it will render just fine with only one call to renderer.render().

The code below shows a simple run method that acts as a loop in order to repeatedly call the render function. By using that function then the cube with it's texture looks great. But if I comment out that method call to disable it and then call the render method just a single time then the cube appears solid black with no visible image texture on it.

var renderer,
      scene,
      camera;

function init() {

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth /       window.innerHeight, 1, 4000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        scene.add(camera);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 1);
        scene.add(light);

        var mapUrl = "images/monster.jpg";
        var monsterMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(mapUrl);

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:monsterMap});

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        cube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 5;
        cube.rotation.y = Math.PI / 5;
        scene.add(cube);

        document.getElementById("WebGL-output")
            .appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        //run();
    }

    function run(){
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(run);
    }

    window.onload = init;
```

EDIT: Thanks @pailhead, @WestLangley .... You were correct as the problem was due to the image not fully loaded before the render method was called. I had to re-write some code but got it to work. The info in your comments is much appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018994/1461008

Comment: @WestLangley is that a good catch-all async loading answer we could point the duplicates at? I've removed [tag:three.js] in the pas leaving it as just a JS question but, maybe that wasnt a great idea.

Comment: @pailhead Duplicates are for duplicate questions, not duplicate answers. I would advise against removing three.js tags if the question pertains to a three.js method.

Comment: I see, I think that makes sense, the specifics here are rendering only once, with an async function happening after that render? My understanding was that specific questions should maybe be digested (could maybe this be shorter while explaining the same request) in which case it may end up being more similar to other questions. But I’m not sure if this would end up being a duplicate probably not.