# How to add texture in PlaneGeometry

Tags: three.js

How can I add texture to `PlaneGeometry`? Here is my code. Currently, it only diplay black. When I remove the parameters in `MeshBasicMaterial` it display a white square.

```
var container, mesh;

container = document.getElementById( 'threejs2' );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

scene.add(camera)

var texture = new THREE.Texture('https://images.pexels.com/photos/358482/pexels-photo-358482.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb')
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texture
});
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 32 );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( mesh );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: container,
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018994/1461008 for how to load a texture properly.

Comment: Pulling textures from external sources can trigger CORS issues. It's better to host the texture locally which will also help with load times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `THREE.TextureLoader` for this, which provides the preferred method for loading and assigning textures to materials.

When the texture loads, it will be displayed on any geometry that is using the `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` material:

```
var container, mesh;

container = document.getElementById( 'threejs2' );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

scene.add(camera)

// Make use of the `TextureLoader` object to handle asynchronus loading and
// assignment of the texture to your material    
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load( 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/358482/pexels-photo-358482.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb', 
function ( texture ) {    

    // The texture has loaded, so assign it to your material object. In the 
    // next render cycle, this material update will be shown on the plane 
    // geometry
    material.map = texture;
    material.needsUpdate = true;
});

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 32 );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( mesh );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: container,
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

// [UPDATE]
function renderFrame() {
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  window.requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
}
renderFrame();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question and explaining things. I try to paste your updated code but still it display white square and not the image. I also try to use another image just in case, same result. Im really new in using threejs. sorry.

Comment: Hi @user3779015 , please see update at bottom of code sample

Comment: @user3779015 also note that `material.needsUpdate = true;` has been added

Comment: Thank you @Darce Denny, It's working! im stuck with this for days!.